# rotating a matrix in one direction

Tags: android, matrix, bitmap, rotation, image-rotation

is there a way to make an image matrix rotates in one direction only  ie: anti-clock wise ?

this is my rotate function

```
void rotate(int x, int y) {

        this.matrix.postRotate((float) (this.startAngle - this.currentAngle),
                x, y);
    }
```

and this is ma `onTouch` event

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

            ring_gear.setCurrentAngle((float) ring_gear.getAngle(
                    event.getX(), event.getY()));
            ring_gear.rotate(ring_gear.Width / 2, ring_gear.Height / 2);

            ring.setImageMatrix(ring_gear.matrix);

            ring_gear.startAngle = ring_gear.currentAngle;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're always doing postRotate. This concats the previous rotation to the current, effectively adding the angle to the rotation on every move event.

If I understood what you're trying to do correctly (move the ring to the position of the finger), then you simply need to set the rotation of the ring, not add it.

Replace this line:

```
this.matrix.postRotate((float) (this.startAngle - this.currentAngle), x, y);
```

To this:

```
this.matrix.setRotation((float) (this.currentAngle), x, y);
```

No need to continuously add the angle, simply set it to what it currently is.

Note:

Also, pay attention to the angle type conversion. IF I'm not mistaken, Matrix uses degrees to calculate a rotation. I'm not sure how you're converting the x/y of the touch to an angle, but if you're using Math.atan2, then you should remember that atan2 uses radians, and so you need to be sure to convert the angle type to degrees before passing it to the matrix.